# Arguments of same length Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write a function in Typescript as follows

`x, y => void`

Where `x` is an array of type `string[]` and `y` is an array of type `string[][]`, but I'd like to constrain `y` so that the inner arrays *must have the same length* as array `x`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022**
It might be done in a much easier and less verbose way:

```js
function array<X extends unknown[], Y extends X[]>(x: [...X], y: [...Y]) {
    return [1, 2, 3] as any
}

const result = array([1, 2, 3], [[1, 1, 1]]) // ok

const result2 = array([1, 2, 3], [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]) // expected error

const result3 = array([1, 2, 3], [[1, 1, 1], [1]]) // expected error

const result4 = array([1, 2], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]) // ok

const result5 = array([1, 2], [[1, 1], [1]]) // expected error
```

### I just was not aware about variadic tuple types 1 year ago :D

Yes, this is possible.

**CONSIDER THIS SOLUTION AS A DEPRECATED ONE**

Here is my solution:

```js
/**
 * Second approach, is more advanced and it is exactly what you are looking for
 */
type ArrayElement = number
type Array1D = ReadonlyArray<ArrayElement>
type Array2D = ReadonlyArray<Array1D>

type MutableLength = unknown[]['length'] // number

/**
 * Get length of the array
 * Allow only immutable arrays
 */
export type Length<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = T extends { length: infer L } ? MutableLength extends L ? MutableLength : L : MutableLength;

/**
 * Compare length of the arrays
 */
type CompareLength<X extends ReadonlyArray<any>, Y extends ReadonlyArray<any>> =
    MutableLength extends Length<X> ? false : MutableLength extends Length<Y> ? false : Length<X> extends Length<Y> ? true : false;

/**
 * Check if all arrays (union type) have same length as X
 */
type Filter<X extends ReadonlyArray<any>, Y extends ReadonlyArray<any>> =
    X['length'] extends Y['length']
    ? Y['length'] extends X['length'] ? Y : never : never
{

    /**
     * CompareLength, compares length of X and filtered Y, 
     * if true - return zero index element - ReadonlyArray<ArrayElement>
     * if false - return never
     * 
     * So, if it will return never, then you can't pass second argument,
     * but if you did not provide second argument, you will receive another error - 
     * function expects two arguments
     */
    function array<X extends Array1D, Y extends {
        0: readonly ArrayElement[]
    }[CompareLength<X, Filter<X, Y>> extends true ? 0 : never]>(x: X, y: readonly Y[]): 'put here your returned type'

    function array<X extends Array1D, Y extends readonly ArrayElement[], Z extends CompareLength<X, Y>>(x: X, y: readonly Y[]) {
        return [1, 2, 3] as any
    }
    const result = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3]] as const) // ok
    const result0 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [[1, 1, 1]] as const) // ok

    const arr = [1, 2, 3] as const

    const result1 = array([1, 2, 3], [[1, 1, 1], [1]]) // error
    const result2 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2]] as const) // error
    const result3 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [[1, 2]] as const) // error
    const result4 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]] as const) // error

    const result5 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [1] as const) // error
    const result6 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [[1, 2, 3], []] as const) // error
    const result7 = array(arr, [[1, 1, 1]]) // error, because TS is unable to fidure out length of mutable array. 
}
```

I used `number` instead of `string`, because it is easier to type numbers instead of strings.

Feel free to change it `ArrayElement` to `string`

Please keep in mind, that you should use every time `as const` to infer array length

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhlBTAxgewHYBNIEMAOOBOyWiAFgDSQCWAzpALbL7zboBuWqi8mHmlALlVrwAHsX4AbAJ6QA7iSyCpyAK7YmkCcmQBrSqgDmkAGaMoIYOH5SczAIL58WKQFEJ8OvFSCAvJFQqdABG8PhWNvaOzgCMACKQfgBK8FjoaNIOTlIAPJnObh5e-AB84baQeVIATPFJKWmoGVE5lXGlZcwAsir8WEHuADJeBvwkCZAqqDqoyLKoANoAuvMA5O6GoyuLkMDA-oEhYeCgENCQAOLwgusjY8jGkKPMWM3mFRJaspDpMpR0dD0%20u51FlqOZLKIcIxBNZykMNiRsgAVSCifhedC0ZKpH6VbIcKTFYrjFFojG0ADemmGowAXFRUMZQpABpAAL6QAD8kG6vX68Hht1RInRGForO5vKBAppY3prPpUv5gtGAG5wMcwG8AMLIOg4F7MG6jb4PJ4g5xg6CWWHMXX6w0qxEADWFosxkGxDSaWXxqEJFAAmm7yZ76rjmn7CcSfFBIPGlYNZSGxSzZdlncTucYsBJqMxFYDlcmyamndlA1mTLn85B5enMymPeXK1zHvgVAXq3n4OrNacYNqSEgdFQHrmJBapLQABSTShoR4RACUkAUrGY1CwnmpCOwtGd4I6kAAYpQJOj8Bmm1jw40pHiCcUgzewzj74--UTxoHVsaSFsr7On%20sqAdywb0qg8AbmEFIavG8YnHGCGDnqBpME6FAoA6TC0P%20pqQK6vAmOel7cJAgYUMh8YwJQZodswAC0kBMPwKj4KgkAAF6hMgDLoKIqLuJ43iQMxXoRr6lQFCJJTUWcdHdrWzGsexnFQTB8kwFpcDIBQikCHI56TqpHH%20NBoQUE8nHKGoiAcCsggGtQtD5igGDqAYgRFGQOlBD0Y6QLZkDoJQmAzE5hCsGFm5IGgPD4F5skUMFsjGSxSDwJQG7YBFw74KijiMGJkA6cYkyIPwC6cZCSD8LQ-CyHxLxJUUVoIda1HlZwVWLi8vquqWHqtLEL5DZS8kIQADPSTDvtIFTNDJRRLNRbLzPa6EygiGYUGeF6hLtFHfuN7adm2U11uZMGLMUM4iPSzopbNd4Lb%20izLvSKw4AF%20XMLZBWmVBmC2is8EId1lXVVO16nSNY0iqGc3ejI0nCStiwUAAWq%20m2Og2QZEvdj3PRl80yO9q5wR1HVA5A8zRBQVQUAAzNsWC0ASa3Ue51CCLhKgXuM-XODODNM6z7O0Lz-AUPM4uQIziuY-TSvM5AbNS5AMurrs3w6DzaB8xl1CC-wl1%20CLUhi2rkv7trRuy-TCtK9EixazrOx7Lo4PxjLILjAr6ts-bMu%20w7qDGwLF7RMLzQ2xLGsq-LrsUG7ctux9XuFYQYQdf70f8FUcdZAnkDBx7jtyy7afJ2r7uh47ut7KEueG5H-PwKbF4syXotB3bHMR3z1f15XHfNznZj547JtmwArH31sD0njcdxn4985PrfTwhBddwvS9lxXa8j87ttJ3LDdD57es73ne%20z4XABsR-9aPae11nd9FfgFAhPZFQtYkSwCEBMVA0pHh8WMGFdizBVDXGTPcegRZgRWwAHSlTZOAIAA)