# Is there a way to enforce an array size declaration based on another array size when declaring types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to define an interface for function parameters. Consider we have two parameters, both of type `array` and one is dependent on the other in terms of another one's length and containing elements' type(Elements are of the same type).

Is there a way to declare one of them as lengthy as another one?

Comment: Pleese see this article https://catchts.com/compare-arguments
Could you please provide more examples ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian - It's important to disclose your affiliation when you link to your own blog. (It doesn't have to be a big thing, just "See my article here:" for instance.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, nice catch. I will keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE January 30 2022**

There is much easier  and less verbose way to do it:

```js
type Json =
  | null
  | string
  | boolean
  | number
  | { [prop: string]: Json }
  | Array<Json>

function array<
  Elem,
  First extends Elem[],
  >(x: [...First], y: [...First]) {

}

/**
 * Passed
 */
{
  const _ = array([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]) // ok
  const __ = array(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'x', 'x']) // ok
}


/**
 * Failed
 */
{
  const __ = array([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]) //expected error
  const ___ = array([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) //expected error
  const ____ = array([1], []) //expected error
  const _____ = array([], [1]) //expected error
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wE5R3w)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361696/arguments-of-same-length-typescript) you can find very similar answer

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) you can find more information about inference on function arguments

### **TOOO VERBOSE AND UNEFFECTIVE WAY**

Here you have:

```js
type ArrayElement = number;
type Array1D = ReadonlyArray<ArrayElement>;


type MutableLength = unknown[]["length"]; // number

export type Length<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = T extends { length: infer L }
  ? MutableLength extends L
    ? MutableLength
    : L
  : MutableLength;

type CompareLength<
  X extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  Y extends ReadonlyArray<any>
> = MutableLength extends Length<X>
  ? false
  : MutableLength extends Length<Y>
  ? false
  : Length<X> extends Length<Y>
  ? true
  : false;

type CompareType<
  X extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  Y extends ReadonlyArray<any>
> = X[number] extends Y[number] ? true:false

function array<
    X extends Array1D,
    Y extends {
        0: Array1D
    }[CompareLength<X,Y> extends true? CompareType<X,Y> extends true ?0 : never:never],
    >(x: X, y: Y) {

}
const result = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [1, 2, 3] as const) // ok
const result2 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [1, 2, '3'] as const) // error
const result3 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [1, 2] as const) // error
const result4 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, [] as const) // error
const result5 = array([1, 2, 3] as const, []) // error
const result6 = array([], []) // error, because arrays are mutable. TS is unable to find out the length
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAogGwgWwgO2FAXihwFdMAjCOAbgChRJYFkBGAEUKgCUJEATAPY40IeEhAAeMcnRZcwAHx1a9cNACyJYInIYAMrgDmwABacSOANY4BAdxwBtALoOARBhzGTrp9SgB6f2IySjgVCAAPMAE4fAZoA09TCQAVKEjgXD4AZ25eQWFRZklEHBAFBU40jKzcgG8oDy8ALigASxwAMyooPSgAX1ooKAB%20KE1tXQhEr3SIzJwc3qHh0fGtHX0jUxXh1r0V1onN6e2TZXioAGEBTDBEOFOkkwkVgA05haWefiERaRKZQUABoVgBNT61PK-QoAiSlcq0SpEY5TGamSGLXLol5vBQrMadRBobIQQ7rSZbZ6YpY4iRg-HDQnE0nkul4mnYs70xlrYBwEhkvZQIkkiAXNTXW73R4pNSvYYfGpY6EFf7FeFA0HDCHK775P5FcSaxHIqBvBykChUJycqBgy0hG18gUQZqi1m0ToWADGwDaQigD2Nu3NdoB7G1q118yhdVDqygAAZWhG2KH%20g4bncHk8vBI3sCGXb%20YKxtmZRA5ZAC0XKnrcqXoCMk1BWjgIAA3KjNDvduBOKPDBQACgirULUBArTBAEooPHaIMfUJsvhHtkSGh8ERg8gRw4WMCoAAmY8AZltiFyK5wa%20Ph%20PZ6gl6DN9XwHngSgAkstFva5QBuW7ACenB7iAB5HqeF5Xu%20d7AA%200HPgA5OeKFwVAAGfgEQRUHAMT-h%20QEQJu27nuBxRQU%20sFvlhH5IU%20mHYV%20eEIIR2EkWRwAACyUeI1EwS%20zEMVAzh0SxuHpOxYSccB24AKz8fuj5Ca%20170QhD5OKx0kEXAQA)

[This is my article](https://catchts.com/compare-arguments), here you can find more explanations

Please keep in mind, you should operate only on readonly arrays.

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence. Are you saying the solution only works for read-only arrays, or that in general the OP should only use read-only arrays, or both, or... ? :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes and no ) For instance, if you use only mutable arrays, my solution will throw an error, because TS is unable to find out the length of mutable arrays. I added `result6`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder made an update, this solution works for all arrays, not only for readonly. Did not have much exp that days